# Implementing SoundCloud OAuth Login using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0

I need to implement authentication with SoundCloud in my **Windows Phone app** using **C#**
But I don't know how to get started implementing OAuth in this case. How should I call the Authorization endpoint (https://soundcloud.com/connect) to receive the request token, and then I need to call the token end-point (During this call: All parameters must be sent in the request body, not as part of the query string.)

Answer (score 1):

Devices should typcially implement the **implicit** flow in OAuth2, that doesn't require storing any secrets on the device. Not all OAuth providers implement this flow though, so it is rather tough to do without a server side component that collaborates in the process.

However, a quick glance at [Soundcloud's docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#authentication) shows that they do in fact support it. (See the ["Javascript client-side apps" topic](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#client-side)). The caveat is that this seems primarily focused on web sites (e.g. it will show a popup, which might not work on WP8).

You could also call the underlying endpoint directly using `token_and_code` as the value for `response_type` (this is probably the response you want for the **implicit** flow).

A (likely much simpler & faster) alternative is to use an intermediary service that will negotiate details all for you and happens to support [the exact configuration you are looking for](https://auth0.com/authenticate/windowsphone/soundcloud).

Disclosure: I work for Auth0.